# When comparing to normal distribution using R

Tags: r

When showing the QQ plot between variable, lets say, x and normal distribution, do we type qqplot(x, rnorm) or qqplot(x, qnorm)? And how do we know if x has a normal distribution in the dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `qqnorm`:

```
x <- rnorm(10)
qqnorm(x)
```

[image]